# Node.js: forEach containing promises completed before promises are fulfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to return a result (feedItemsArray) only when all promises inside the forEach loop are fulfilled, but the code is executed before all promises are returned. What is the proper way to make sure all promises are returned beforehand?

```
function retrieveFeed(req, res) {
   return FeedItem.find().exec()
   .then(function(feedItems) {
       var feedItemsArray = [];
       feedItems.forEach(function(feedItem){
          // Do some stuff on feedItem
          return Comment.find({feedItem_id : feedItem._id}).exec()
          .then(function(comments){
             // Do some stuff on comments 
             return feedItemsArray.push(feedItem);  
          })
       })
       return prepareJSONObject(feedItemsArray);
   })
   .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
   .then(respondWithResult(res))
   .catch(handleError(res)); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to work with promises on arrays, you should add them to an array and then use Promise.all() to get the results together.

For example:

```
var arr = ["url1", "url2"];
var promises = [];

// Request is request-promise (returns a promise)
arr.forEach(function(url) {
    promises.push(request.get(url));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of results for each url
}).catch(function(err){
    // Even if one fails, you end up here
});
```